# Merging [del.icio.us] into [delicious]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[del.icio.us](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/del.icio.us) was [delicious](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delicious)' name at the beginning but they've changed their name later. del.icio.us has only two tagged questions.

[delicious](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delicious_%28website%29)

Comment: Simpler to retag since it is only 2 questions.  But what about [tag:delicious-api]?  How does that fit in?